# Como fazer multiplas validations Requests no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, request, validator

O Laravel permite criar Requests para validar campos vindo do front-end, mas eu queria fazer vários Requests para validar um fomulário gigante. É possível? É uma boa prática?

Fiz Traits para que pudessem realizar o cadastro de cada um.

Este são os campos do formulário: Como podem ver estão divido em array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o método na controller que está recebendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function store(DealerRequest $request)
{
    try{

        DB::beginTransaction();
            dd($request->all());
            $dealer = $this->dealer->create($request['dealer']);

            $company = $this->createCompany($dealer, $request);

            $this->createPerson($company, $request);

            $this->createLocation($company, $request);

            $this->createContact($company, $request);

            $this->createContract($company, $request);

        DB::commit();

        event(new Welcome($dealer));
        return redirect()->route('representative.dealers.index');
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        dd($e->getMessage());
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Falha no servidor');
    }
}
```

Este método faz chamadas a outros métodos que realizam inserts no banco de dados. A minha ideia era de em cada método ter uma request validando seus respectivos campos.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function createCompany(Dealer $dealer, CompanyRequest $request){
    try {
        return $dealer->company()->create($request->input());
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Este é um método que instancia uma request, e como ele tem outros instanciando suas respectivas requests. mas ao executar tenho o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma solução melhor, ou como resolver este problema.

Obrigado!!

Comment: Substitua as imagens da usa pergunta por texto e [formate o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Como assim, desculpe, quer que mostre todo o codigo?

Comment: Não XD, apenas converta as imagens para texto e coloque com formatação `deste modo por exemplo`

Comment: Acho eu ... (não tenho como testar) mas, os `traits` estão repetindo o mesmo nome `$request`, tente colocar outro nome tipo `$requestCompany` e assim por diante!

Comment: ok, vou tentar. Obrigado!

Comment: Nçao funcionou, para ajudar a compreender melhor, vejam que quando os dados da requisição entra no método "store()" ele já é instanciado por uma request, entao quando passa os mesmos dados para o metodo createCompany(), o array ja se transformou em objeto e o Laravel não permite com que este objeto faça uma nova instância.

Comment: Eu entendi agora o que você aprontou, isso que você fez não funciona !!! tem que montar outra estratégia, no caso em questão no método Pai de todos chamar todos os request de validação e passar os mesmos correspondentes ao seus métodos internos, outro assunto é desempenho e manutenção, não se isso vai ficar legal.